# AttributeError: 'PLL' object has no attribute 'fast_atan2f'

Tags: python

Пишу блок на Python для GNU Radio. Есть такой код (я вообще не уверен в том правильно ли я написал, т.к.за неделю пришлось разбираться в этой программе и Python). На данный момент выдает такую ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот код:

```
import numpy
import math
from gnuradio import gr

class PLL(gr.sync_block):

def __init__(self, GAIN_PLL, K_PLL, P_PLL):
self.GAIN_PLL=GAIN_PLL
self.P_PLL=P_PLL
self.K_PLL=K_PLL
    gr.sync_block.__init__(self,

        name="PLL",
        in_sig=[numpy.float32],
        out_sig=[numpy.float32])

def fast_atan2f(self, y, x):
    x_abs = 0.0
    y_abs = 0.0 
    z = 0.0
    alpha = 0.0 
    angle = 0.0 
    base_angle = 0.0
    index = 0

    TAN_MAP_RES = 0.003921569
    RAD_PER_DEG = 0.017453293
    TAN_MAP_SIZE = 255

    fast_atan_table = [
    0.000000e+00, 3.921549e-03, 7.842976e-03, 1.176416e-02,
    1.568499e-02, 1.960533e-02, 2.352507e-02, 2.744409e-02,
    3.136226e-02, 3.527947e-02, 3.919560e-02, 4.311053e-02,
    4.702413e-02, 5.093629e-02, 5.484690e-02, 5.875582e-02,
    6.266295e-02, 6.656816e-02, 7.047134e-02, 7.437238e-02,
    7.827114e-02, 8.216752e-02, 8.606141e-02, 8.995267e-02,
    9.384121e-02, 9.772691e-02, 1.016096e-01, 1.054893e-01,
    1.093658e-01, 1.132390e-01, 1.171087e-01, 1.209750e-01,
    1.248376e-01, 1.286965e-01, 1.325515e-01, 1.364026e-01,
    1.402496e-01, 1.440924e-01, 1.479310e-01, 1.517652e-01,
    1.555948e-01, 1.594199e-01, 1.632403e-01, 1.670559e-01,
    1.708665e-01, 1.746722e-01, 1.784728e-01, 1.822681e-01,
    1.860582e-01, 1.898428e-01, 1.936220e-01, 1.973956e-01,
    2.011634e-01, 2.049255e-01, 2.086818e-01, 2.124320e-01,
    2.161762e-01, 2.199143e-01, 2.236461e-01, 2.273716e-01,
    2.310907e-01, 2.348033e-01, 2.385093e-01, 2.422086e-01,
    2.459012e-01, 2.495869e-01, 2.532658e-01, 2.569376e-01,
    2.606024e-01, 2.642600e-01, 2.679104e-01, 2.715535e-01,
    2.751892e-01, 2.788175e-01, 2.824383e-01, 2.860514e-01,
    2.896569e-01, 2.932547e-01, 2.968447e-01, 3.004268e-01,
    3.040009e-01, 3.075671e-01, 3.111252e-01, 3.146752e-01,
    3.182170e-01, 3.217506e-01, 3.252758e-01, 3.287927e-01,
    3.323012e-01, 3.358012e-01, 3.392926e-01, 3.427755e-01,
    3.462497e-01, 3.497153e-01, 3.531721e-01, 3.566201e-01,
    3.600593e-01, 3.634896e-01, 3.669110e-01, 3.703234e-01,
    3.737268e-01, 3.771211e-01, 3.805064e-01, 3.838825e-01,
    3.872494e-01, 3.906070e-01, 3.939555e-01, 3.972946e-01,
    4.006244e-01, 4.039448e-01, 4.072558e-01, 4.105574e-01,
    4.138496e-01, 4.171322e-01, 4.204054e-01, 4.236689e-01,
    4.269229e-01, 4.301673e-01, 4.334021e-01, 4.366272e-01,
    4.398426e-01, 4.430483e-01, 4.462443e-01, 4.494306e-01,
    4.526070e-01, 4.557738e-01, 4.589307e-01, 4.620778e-01,
    4.652150e-01, 4.683424e-01, 4.714600e-01, 4.745676e-01,
    4.776654e-01, 4.807532e-01, 4.838312e-01, 4.868992e-01,
    4.899573e-01, 4.930055e-01, 4.960437e-01, 4.990719e-01,
    5.020902e-01, 5.050985e-01, 5.080968e-01, 5.110852e-01,
    5.140636e-01, 5.170320e-01, 5.199904e-01, 5.229388e-01,
    5.258772e-01, 5.288056e-01, 5.317241e-01, 5.346325e-01,
    5.375310e-01, 5.404195e-01, 5.432980e-01, 5.461666e-01,
    5.490251e-01, 5.518738e-01, 5.547124e-01, 5.575411e-01,
    5.603599e-01, 5.631687e-01, 5.659676e-01, 5.687566e-01,
    5.715357e-01, 5.743048e-01, 5.770641e-01, 5.798135e-01,
    5.825531e-01, 5.852828e-01, 5.880026e-01, 5.907126e-01,
    5.934128e-01, 5.961032e-01, 5.987839e-01, 6.014547e-01,
    6.041158e-01, 6.067672e-01, 6.094088e-01, 6.120407e-01,
    6.146630e-01, 6.172755e-01, 6.198784e-01, 6.224717e-01,
    6.250554e-01, 6.276294e-01, 6.301939e-01, 6.327488e-01,
    6.352942e-01, 6.378301e-01, 6.403565e-01, 6.428734e-01,
    6.453808e-01, 6.478788e-01, 6.503674e-01, 6.528466e-01,
    6.553165e-01, 6.577770e-01, 6.602282e-01, 6.626701e-01,
    6.651027e-01, 6.675261e-01, 6.699402e-01, 6.723452e-01,
    6.747409e-01, 6.771276e-01, 6.795051e-01, 6.818735e-01,
    6.842328e-01, 6.865831e-01, 6.889244e-01, 6.912567e-01,
    6.935800e-01, 6.958943e-01, 6.981998e-01, 7.004964e-01,
    7.027841e-01, 7.050630e-01, 7.073330e-01, 7.095943e-01,
    7.118469e-01, 7.140907e-01, 7.163258e-01, 7.185523e-01,
    7.207701e-01, 7.229794e-01, 7.251800e-01, 7.273721e-01,
    7.295557e-01, 7.317307e-01, 7.338974e-01, 7.360555e-01,
    7.382053e-01, 7.403467e-01, 7.424797e-01, 7.446045e-01,
    7.467209e-01, 7.488291e-01, 7.509291e-01, 7.530208e-01,
    7.551044e-01, 7.571798e-01, 7.592472e-01, 7.613064e-01,
    7.633576e-01, 7.654008e-01, 7.674360e-01, 7.694633e-01,
    7.714826e-01, 7.734940e-01, 7.754975e-01, 7.774932e-01,
    7.794811e-01, 7.814612e-01, 7.834335e-01, 7.853982e-01,
    7.853982e-01        
    ]
    y_abs = math.fabs(y)
    x_abs = math.fabs(x)

        if(not((y_abs > 0.0) or (x_abs > 0.0))):
            return 0.0

        if y_abs < x_abs:
            z = y_abs / x_abs

        else:
            z = x_abs / y_abs

        if z < TAN_MAP_RES:
            base_angle = z

        else:
            alpha = z * float(TAN_MAP_SIZE)
            index = int(alpha) & 0xff
            alpha -= float(index)

            base_angle  =  fast_atan_table[index]
            base_angle += (fast_atan_table[index + 1] - fast_atan_table[index]) * alpha

        if x_abs > y_abs:

            if x >= 0.0: 

                if y >= 0.0:
                    angle = base_angle

                else:
                    angle = -base_angle

            else: 
                angle = 3.14159265358979323846

            if y >= 0.0:
                angle -= base_angle

            else:
                angle = base_angle - angle

        else: 
            if y >= 0.0:
                angle = 1.57079632679489661923

                if x >= 0.0:
                    angle -= base_angle

                else:
                    angle += base_angle
            else:
                angle = -1.57079632679489661923

                if x >= 0.0:
                    angle += base_angle

                else:
                    angle -= base_angle

    if angle < 0:
        return (angle + (2*math.pi))

    else:
        return (angle)

def work(self, input_items, output_items):

    Re = input_items[0]
    out = output_items[0]

arg = 0.0

for i in range(0, len (input_items)):

    I = Re[i]

    demo = self.fast_atan2f(I.imag, I.real)
    demo = demo*self.P_PLL

    out[i] = demo*self.GAIN_PLL
    arg = arg+self.K_PLL*demo

    if arg > (2*math.pi):
        arg = arg - (2*math.pi)
    elif arg < (-2*math.pi):
        arg = arg + (2*math.pi)

    return len(output_items[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не соблюдена табуляция внутри объявления класса PLL, поэтому все объявленные функции не являются методами экземпляров класса PLL.
Вот и выдает ошибку о том, что не существует у объекта класса PLL такого атрибута как "fast_atan2f"

Все что объявляется в классе должно быть блоком кода с табуляцией от блока, где объявлен класс, ровно также как и в функциях. Не забудьте также табуляцию внутри методов класса!